# Pandas read_csv(): keeping the header and then skip rows when reading in from file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to read in every 500th line of a input file.

My idea was using a lambda function to create my booleans with: `skiprows = lambda x: 0 != x%500`
This works fine, but also skips my first line, which I want to keep as header.

I tried working around this with the `header` argument in `read_csv()` but can't figure it out.

My code:

```
tsteps = [ 12500, 25000, 50000 ,100000, 200000, 400000, 800000, 1600000, 3200000 ]

list_of_data = [pd.read_csv("../data/gauss_wf_fixed_wall6_129_1_{}_1_3_30_6_1.txt".format(i), sep="\t", header=0 ,skiprows = lambda x: 0 != x%500) for i in tsteps ]
```

Current Output:

```
   3.9920000000000004e-02  2.2889406468048764e-314  1.9631275851119487e-01  \
0                 0.08000            2.288941e-314                0.196313   
1                 0.12008            2.288941e-314                0.196313   
2                 0.16016            2.288941e-314                0.196313   
3                 0.20024            2.288941e-314                0.196313   
4                 0.24032            2.288941e-314                0.196313   ...
```

Wanted Output: (something like)

```
      time   REAL(psi[n])  IMAG(psi[n])      averx    deltax     averp  \
0  0.00000  2.328125e-314      0.000000  30.000020  5.999985  0.838554   
1  0.00004  2.328125e-314      0.196313  30.000034  5.999985  0.838554   
2  0.00008  2.328125e-314      0.196313  30.000048  5.999985  0.838554   
3  0.00012  2.328125e-314      0.196313  30.000063  5.999985  0.838554   
4  0.00016  2.328125e-314      0.196313  30.000077  5.999985  0.838554
```

Might there be a way to call skip header before applying skiprows?
(As skiprows skips trough all rows in the file)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the effect by forcibly keeping the first row and then shifting the remaining rows up by 1 and then applying the modulus operator. 'keep' are the rows to keep, and then we negate it inside the lambda func.

```
def keep(x):
    if x==0:
        return True
    if (x-1) % 500 ==0:
        return True

df=pd.read_csv("ummh.csv", header=0, skiprows=lambda x: not keep(x))
```